MySQL query where the order by value has an exception
I have a table that contains a bunch of values for various "trouble ticket" parts, most specifically one called "TicketStatus" and of course one called "DateCreated".  I am struggling to write a query that displays all my tickets in date descending order, but with the COMPLETED tickets listed after those with other status (new/pending/assigned/inprogress, etc).
If I ignore the TicketStatus then my query is:
SELECT * FROM tickets ORDER BY `DateCreated` DESC;
I could run two queries back to back and put them together afterwords:
SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE `TicketStatus`!= 'Completed' ORDER BY `DateCreated` DESC;
SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE `TicketStatus`= 'Completed'  ORDER BY `DateCreated` DESC;
But I am confident there is a way to do some magic in my ORDER BY clause to simply "sink" the "completed" ones to the bottom?  I tried:
SELECT * FROM tickets ORDER BY `TicketStatus`='Completed', `DateCreated` DESC; but that definitely does not work.
Thanks!

Not sure there is enough data to for me to help you here (i.e. minimal schema, example data, expected output).  If nothing else you can union two selects.  You could map the TicketStatus to a numeric column with case and order by that column.

I think, this union should do what you're asking for. Basically, add a literal value column that identifies each portion of the data
SELECT incomp.*, 1 specialOrder 
FROM tickets incomp 
WHERE `TicketStatus`!= 'Completed' 

UNION ALL

SELECT comp.*, 2 specialOrder 
FROM tickets comp
WHERE `TicketStatus`= 'Completed'
ORDER BY specialOrder, `DateCreated` DESC;

oh, you're using same table.. Can do this
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tickets
ORDER BY
  (
    CASE WHEN TicketStatus = 'Completed' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
  ),
  DateCreated DESC;

TEST
create table T (a int, b varchar(20), c datetime);
insert into T values (1, 'aaa', now(3) + 1);
insert into T values (2, 'bbb', now(3) + 2);
insert into T values (3, 'aaa', now(3) + 3);
insert into T values (4, 'bbb', now(3) + 4);
insert into T values (5, 'aaa', now(3) + 5);
insert into T values (6, 'bbb', now(3) + 6);

SELECT *
FROM
  T
ORDER BY
  (
    CASE WHEN b = 'aaa' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
  ),
  c DESC;

--a     b       c
--6     bbb     2024-08-14 01:34:11
--4     bbb     2024-08-14 01:34:09
--2     bbb     2024-08-14 01:34:07
--5     aaa     2024-08-14 01:34:10
--3     aaa     2024-08-14 01:34:08
--1     aaa     2024-08-14 01:34:06


OOH...I have not heard of "CASE"...that is brilliant.  Thanks!  I will try it now and then accept this answer if it works.
